# Best way to disable text selection and image download on mobile only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm planning to use this to achieve that

```
-webkit-touch-callout:none;
-webkit-user-select:none;
-khtml-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Just wondering, is there a better, or more neat way to achieve that? I only want to disable text selection (copy paste) and image download on mobile. I know user can still do that with otherways and it's not very user friendly. I'm already aware of the negatives assosciated with it.

Thanks!

Comment: you can try adding `pointer-events: none` on media query for mobile devices.

Comment: But that would make the image unclickable too so that's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

A media query with the following would prevent the user selecting any of the text. Touch callouts are just the blue highlight.

```
body, html {
    user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That wouldn't prevent image download though, right ?

Comment: If you wanted to prevent long presses and right clicks you could add `$("img").on("contextmenu",function(e){
     return false;
});` or `$("body").on("contextmenu",function(e){
     return false;
});` with JS. There's not a CSS feature to prevent that as far as I'm aware. All images are downloadable if a user really wants to. You could place images as backgrounds in DIVs if you want to make them harder to access.